# Send mail to different customer on their birthday

Tags: php, apache

I have found that there is related topic.However, there are some difference because the people is asking for ubuntu server but i am using the **Apache (xampp****)** the latest version, so are there any method to let the system automatically send mail by checking the date ?
Can it applies to some schedule sending as well? thanks

I have the script for sending it , the only thing *i need is how to schedule  send*.

Edit:
Make it simpler , assuming only windows is the only platform. **Can i do some php script and create the cron job in os , so that my client can schedule their mail in my system instead of doing it in the os**?

3 rd party cron job is good suggestion but there is limitation (what if their service break down etc...) and i want everything is based on own system
[image]

Comment: cron job, check db for date, send email, that as much help as i can give base on the above.

Comment: @user782104: its explained [here](http://docs.phplist.com/SendMessageSchedulingInfo)(this is the time checking script) and then [here](http://docs.phplist.com/ProcessQueueInfo)(This is a script to be called by cron).  Which internally means, that they have already setup the cron.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If your xampp is on Windows, you can use [windows-schedulers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569) to call a particular script (PHP script in your case, preferably by an URL), which checks the birthdays of all the users and sends them mail accordingly.
2. If your xampp is on Linux/Unix/etc, you can use [cron-jobs](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/), and rest is same!
3. There is also a third way, a third-party scheduler or say [online-cron](http://www.onlinecronjobs.com/), which will remotely call yours script (php-page).

**Example:**

If you are doing the cron-settings of OS yourself, you can still let the configure as to whom to email in your system, rather than OS.

After all, a cron so is to do something repeatedly, in your case, its just calling your scripts, by an URL.

Now regarding the time settings, you can make the CRON call your script every hour, and your php script will check the appropriate time, and fire the mails!

Comment: Because my system is not depend on the os, and it makes my product inflexible if i  ask my client to do windows schedulers  by themselves after buying the software, are there any recommendation on that? thank you

Comment: I have added links with the words, those links should help you :) and in that case, online-cron seems more appropriate for you :) the third category I specified!

Comment: make it simpler , assuming only windows is the only platform. Can i do some php script and create the cron job , so that my client can schedule their mail in my system instead of doing it in the os? thank you again for your suggestion

Comment: @user782104 updated answer accordingly! with an Example! Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, instead of using windows-schedulers, can i create a cron file (sya,corn_confing.txt), with time and php file on each line,  in appache ,and it run when the server is operation? I am just imaging if there is some function like that..

Comment: Apache won't do the cron job for you, either you should use windows-scheduler, or online-schedulers. Regarding creating a config.txt, you can still do that, like making the php file read that config.txt and acting accordingly. But you need some schedulers do call your php file, and apache won't do it for you.

Comment: I see. That means if my client use my product , thay have to doing it by themselves on os, (select the php file, select the freq...) instead of setting them in my system? (assuming not using online cron scheduler)

Comment: @user782104 No!, FOR ONCE, you HAVE TO set that for your client in the OS. and then you can handle everything in your php script. now it would depend more about programming experience and product complexity!

Comment: Sorry not clear about it, how can i set that in my client os? I can't access to my cilent server / os

Comment: @user782104 yup, in that case, you surely can't, except resorting to online-scheduler. Sorry If I misunderstood something.

Comment: That is fine .You understand exactly what i  want to ask. but as you can see http://dev.phplist.com/lists/admin/?page=send&id=106&tab=Scheduling 
, how this plugin can do this kind of job ?

Comment: it seems cannot visit the link directly.Please see the screenshot , Thank you a lot.

Comment: @user782104: its explained [here](http://docs.phplist.com/SendMessageSchedulingInfo)(this is the time checking script) and then [here](http://docs.phplist.com/ProcessQueueInfo)(This is a script to be called by cron). Which internally means, that they have already setup the cron.

Comment: Last question, any suggestion of the scheduler for Apache ?
is this one http://www.phpjobscheduler.co.uk/ suitable for me to do this and my cilent doesn't need to set it in os?

Comment: @user782104 : it can work. Infact there are some ways like using continuous ajax, to do the same task, but what if the page is not accessed at all? then there wont be any call to your php and therefore no hit. about phpjobscheduler, its new to me, you should work on it,and test it, if it works, its great.

Comment: @user782104 : please check on that link, the section **Limiting Factor** which puts it back to the same problem! :), If you don't have enough traffic to your site, you can't expect it to work correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

schedule a script in `crontab` or `scheduler` which will check the birthday of your customer

and send them an email

this script will run everyday at particular time of the day

Answer (score 0):

use server cron job to run a script that will send out email. ur script should compare current's date and customer's birthday date.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cron-job. With PHP that get all the people that you want to send an email and gets template and send it just substitute the name and other stuff

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Wishing Application](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app). [Getting started](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Getting-Started) provides good details on how to kick started. At minimal you need only **two** things the **excel file** having wish details (Birthday and on work anniversary), and a **configuration file** (application.properties) to provide the mapping details and other configurations. There are various options to [run](https://github.com/mnadeem/wishing-app/wiki/Running) this application, locally (background, foreground, docker, windows-scheduler etc) on cloud

Disclaimer : I am the owner of application.