# How to send email in accordance with the time we set in PHP

Tags: php, email

i want to ask something.
Maybe I will explain the scenario first :

1. When someone buy an item from my online shop and then they checkout, I send them email about what they buy.
2. After 1 hour they buy, i want to make some notification for them using email and send to them they must confirm the payment and every 3 hour the same email will be send to them and that email will be send just 3 time in one day. Example: they buy some item at 12.00, at 13.00
   the system will automatically send notification to them to confirm the payment,at 16.00 and 19.00 system will send the same email notification again.
3. If in one day they don't confirm the payment, system not send the notification again and cancel the order or if they already confirm the payment before deadline, system not send the notification again.

How can i achieve the solution for a question 2 and 3?
Thank you so much for your response and solution..

Comment: You're looking for cron jobs (search eg. `php cron`), but are you sure this is a good idea? I'd cancel any order with an online shop that pesters me about payment every hour.

Comment: Scheduler, on unix systems you have cron and on windows you have the windows task manager. Put the messages into a queue and check the queue every minute or so.

Comment: @Pekka, I don't think I'd use a website where the payment is a completely separate process from checkout.

Comment: @datasage how can i do it? and how to write in php code? Any all of you know how to set a cron job?

Comment: `cron` is good for repeating jobs. you'd set up a script to check "is there any mail to do?" every 5 minutes or whatever. if you need those emails to go out EXACTLY 1hour later, then use `at`, which is good for one-shot non-repeating jobs at specific times.

Answer (score 0):

If your xampp is on Windows, you can use windows-schedulers to call a particular script (PHP script in your case, preferably by an URL), which checks the birthdays of all the users and sends them mail accordingly.

If your xampp is on Linux/Unix/etc, you can use cron-jobs, and rest is same!

There is also a third way, a third-party scheduler or say online-cron, which will remotely call yours script (php-page).

```
**Example:**
```

If you are doing the cron-settings of OS yourself, you can still let the configure as to whom to email in your system, rather than OS.

Now regarding the time settings, you can make the CRON call your script every our, and you php script will check the appropriate time, and fire the mails!

**Refrence** [Send mail to different customer on their birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9494057/send-mail-to-different-customer-on-their-birthday)